# How to make a Discord bot alert conditionally?

Tags: python, discord

I am learning on how to make a discord bot and I am trying to make one that sends out a message whenever an if statement is fulfilled but my code isn't entering into the async. In this example, I am using a timer for my if statement but I would like to use other conditions like through web scrapping a page in the future. All the other events works just fine but events that activates automatically from the bot, that means without user messaging on discord, seems to not work here.

```
import discord
import time


class discordSection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = "token here"
        self.channel = 856683116419481645
        self.server = 856683116419481640



    def bot(self):
        client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

        @client.event
        async def on_ready():                   # <<<< this one works fine
            print("bot is online as {0.user}".format(client))


        @client.event
            async def on_message(message):         # this one works fine as well
                if message.author == client.user:
                    return
                if message.channel.name == "general":
                    if len(str(message)) > 3:            # if the user types anything longer than 3 characters, a response is given
                        await message.channel.send(f"<@{382761544481636352}> follow me")

        @client.event
        async def scheduleMessage():       # <<<<< code isn't entering into this async and outputting a message
            print("debug: entered into scheduleMessage")
            count = 0
            channel = client.get_channel(self.channel)

            for i in range(100):
                count += 1
                time.sleep(1)
                if count == 10:        
                    count = 0
                    await channel.send("Good Morning folks")


        client.run(self.token)



def main():
    discordSection().bot()

main()
```